# Simplifying $\cos(\arcsin x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I remember reading somewhere that we can simplify $\cos(\arcsin x)$ and $\sin(\arccos x)$ in terms of a polynomial by making the substitution $m=\arcsin x$ or $m=\arccos x$ (respectively), then constructing a right angle triangle with appropriate ratios. Does anyone know what I'm talking about? I don't really remember how to do this, so if someone can show me I would really appreciate it!

Thanks.

Comment: You probably mean expressions like $cos^{-1}(sin(x))$, no?

Comment: in this case use the identity ${\cos{(x)}}^{2}+{\sin{(x)}}^{2} = 1$

Comment: $$\arcsin(\cos x)=\arcsin(\sin(\pi/2-x))=\pi/2-x,$$ if that is what you meant.

Comment: You may expand the functions to a polynomial by well known methods: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html  Here you will find the cos and sin expansions. Use cos expansion and replace x with sin...

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed.  It happens that there is no interesting answer.  But how could the OP have known this *a priori*?  For example, if he had asked about $\cos(m \cos^{-1}(x))$, he would have received interesting lectures on Tchebychev polynomials.

Comment: Thank you all for your input, it turns out I was thinking of cos( arcsinx ) and sin ( arccos x), how would we simplify those?

Comment: I think here it is just what you were looking for (see the table): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions

Comment: yes it is thanks !

Answer (score 26, accepted):

$$\cos(\arcsin x) = \sqrt{1 - \sin(\arcsin x)^2} = \sqrt{1-x^2}$$

This is the quick and dirty solution, I'll leave you to figure out the intricacies of the sign and the respective domains. Of course, you can simplify the other expression the same way.