# Algebraic manipulations of sin and arcsin

Tags: calculus

I was asked to solve $\int{\sqrt{9-x^2}dx}$.

So I used trigonometric substitution and got $$ \frac{9}{2} \arcsin {\frac{x}{3}}+\frac{9}{4}\sin(2\arcsin{\frac{x}{3}}) +C $$

How can I find the $\frac{9}{4}\sin(2\arcsin(\frac{x}{3}))$ part?

The actual solution to the integral is $$ \frac{9}{2} \arcsin {\frac{x}{3}}+\frac{x\sqrt{9-x^2}}{2} +C $$

Comment: To compute he sine of $2$ times anything, use the double-angle formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\sin(2\arcsin(t))=2\sin(\arcsin(t))\cos(\arcsin(t))=2t\sqrt{1-t^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Use $\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x$ and $\sin(\arcsin x)=x, \cos(\arcsin x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

By simplicity, let us denote $\alpha = \arcsin(x/3)$. Then $\sin(2\arcsin(x/3)) = \sin(2\alpha) = 2\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha) = 2\frac{x}{3} \cos(\alpha)$. Thus:
$$\frac{9}{4}\sin(2\arcsin(x/3)) = \frac{3}{2}x\cos(\arcsin(x/3))$$
Now, [as you can see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388345/simplifying-cos-arcsin-x/1388484), we have $\cos(\arcsin(x)) = \sqrt{1-x^{2}}$, so the above becomes:
$$\frac{9}{4}\sin(2\arcsin(x/3)) = \frac{3}{2}x\sqrt{1-\frac{x^{2}}{9}} $$

Answer (score 0):

$arcsin{\frac{x}{3}}=\alpha$

$sin\alpha=\frac{x}{3}$

$sin2\alpha=2\times\frac{x}{3}\times\frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}}{3}$,since $cos\alpha=  \frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}}{3}$

$\frac{9}{4}sin(2arcsin\frac{x}{3})=\frac{9}{4}\times2 \times\frac{x}{3}\times\frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}}{3}= \frac{x\sqrt{9-x^2}}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=\arcsin(\frac{x}{3}),$ then $x=3\sin(y)$.

So since $\sin(2\arcsin(\frac{x}{3}))=\sin(2y)=2\sin(y)\cos(y)$ and $\sin^2{y}+\cos^2{y}=1$ you have

$$\cos^{2}(y)=1-\frac{x^2}{9}\implies\cos(y)=\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{9}}$$

$$\therefore \sin(2\arcsin(\frac{x}{3}))=2\sin(y)\cos(y)=\frac{2x}{3}\sqrt{\frac{9-x^2}{9}}=\frac{2}{9}x\sqrt{9-x^2}$$

Now multiply this by $\frac{9}{4}$ and you get the required result.